# How to enable downloading of dynamically generated files from a browser?

Tags: java, dynamic, workflow, download

I have a web application in which one of the workflows, users can download files that are dynamically generated. The input is a form which has parameters needed to generate the file.

My current solution is to let them submit this form & on the servlet side I change the response header - content disposition to be an attachment & also provide an appropriate mime-type.

But I find this approach to be inadequate. Because there are chances that the generation of file can take a very long time, in such cases after a certain timeout I directly get 500 or 503 errors in the browser. I guess this is to be expected for the current approach.

I want my workflow to be flexible enough to tell the users as soon as they submit the form that it might take time for the file to generate & that we will display the link to the file as soon as it is ready. I guess I can also email the file or this message to them, but this is not ideal.

Can you guys suggest me an approach for this problem? Should I be more specific in providing information? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this synchronously (i.e. make the user wait for the document to be ready rather than have them go off and do other things while waiting) a traditional approach is to bring them to a "report loading" page.

This would be a page that:

- 1) informs them that the report is loading.
- 2) refreshes itself (either using the meta refresh tag or javascript)
- 3) upon refresh, checks to see if the report is ready and either:

  - a) goes back to step 1 if it isn't ready
  - b) gives them the document if it is ready.

Synchronous is kind of old-school, but your question sounded like that was the approach you wanted.

Asynchronous approaches would include:

- Use Ajax to make a link to the document appear on the page once it is ready.
- Have a separate page that shows previously generated documents. The use can go to this page at their leisure, and, meanwhile, they can browse the rest of the site. This requires keeping a history of generated documents.
- As you suggested, send it via e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an asynchronous Ajax Call to the server with the form data instead of submiting the form direct. 
On the server you create a temp file and return a link to the client with the download URL. 
After submitting the answer via Javascript you can show the user a hint, that the download link will appear in a minute. Don't forget to cleanup the temp file!

For submitting the Ajax Call I would suggest using an Javascript Framework. Have a look at JQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: Ok, thanks Andreas. I use jQuery extensively in my codebase.:) As har as creating temp. file in concerned, would you suggest a cron job to clean up these files or some other mechanism?